# How to order Low Search results by Low Reorder Set?

Tags: low-search, low-reorder

I know it's possible to sort Low Search results by a Low Reorder set (http://gotolow.com/addons/low-reorder/changelog), but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do it.

I have a Low Reorder set named "lr_locations". This is my results tag:

```
{exp:low_search_results default:orderby_sort="lr_locations|asc" ...}
```

Is this the correct way to do this? I cannot find the documentation that speaks to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `orderby="low_reorder:lr_locations"`.

Comment: Duh! I really should have been able to figure that out. Thank you sir! BTW, I feel like you and Croxton make some of the best add-ons. I don't know how I'd do my job without your contributions.